# view.run_command("example") not working

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I created first plugin for `sublime text 3` with name `relative`:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class ExampleCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.insert(edit, 0, "Hello, World!")
```

Then save it to path

```
/pathToSublime3/Packages/relative/relative.py
```

Then try to test it in command window `` (cntrl + `) ``:

```
view.run_command('example')
```

I expected to see `Hello, World!` in the beginning of current opened file, but fail. What I do wrong?

Comment: Your plugin works fine in Sublime Text 2, with either double or single quotes around the word example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I need is close `sublime text 3` and open it again. Now `Hello World` works fine

Comment: Still not working for me. I saved the file into packages/anotherName
And i open up that command line (does it need to have # inside??) and using that, with "example" doesn't work at all. Doesn't add any text.

Answer (score 2):

If your experience was like mine, you may have copied several super basic plugins to try to find one that worked. I think the failure of the others was affecting the Hello World one. For what it's worth, here are the things I did that seem to have worked.

I'm using **ST3** on Win7, so maybe there are differences in plugin development between that and ST2.

*Note that as I tried **many** different permutations of these, I don't exactly know which ones are the real fix.  But if these get you working, then maybe you can start making incremental changes and see when it breaks.*

- Moved all *.py files that were my plugins into "Packages" folder. (I read many posts that said that plugin files in the "Packages\User" or "Packages\NameOfPlugin" folder should be read, but I haven't tried them yet. I put it in "Packages" to make sure that finding the files wasn't a problem.)
- Restart Sublime after every change. (The docs say you don't have to, but if you have errors in your plugins, it seems that the auto-reload feature doesn't work.  Which kinda makes sense. Once I got the errors out of all my plugins, the auto-reload feature started working correctly.)
- A few of the simple/tutorial plugins I copied off the web (even some from sublimetext.com!) referenced/imported "sublimePlugin" which errorred on my ST3 Win7 instance.  Apparently the correct library to import is **"sublime_plugin"**.  The two places this is used, in basic plugins, are 1) at the very top in the import section, as well as 2) in the class line, which I'll illustrate below...

  ```
  # didn't work for me...
  class ExampleCommand(sublimePlugin.TextCommand):

  # DID work for me...
  class ExampleCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
  ```

Comment: Yes. Moving it from the `Packages/User` folder into the `Packages` folder fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

'Ctrl+N' create a new file, then try it again. Don't run it in the old file.

Answer (score 0):

The console doesn't open with Ctrl + `  For Sublime Text 2, but this example is written in the v2 documentation.

Using that command opens up a popup starting with # which is to open another file.

The console opens by doing Ctrl + F1. After that, you can write that code in there, and the text will be added into your current view (in any view, in fact).

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to read the "[Where to Store Plugins](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/plugins.html#where-to-store-plugins)", I made the mistake of creating a folder (package) when the `hello_world.py` is simply a plugin. Also keep in mind from the documentation [window commands](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/plugins.html#window-commands) and [text commands](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/plugins.html#text-commands), cause in this case since it is a text command you must execute it in the "view" that you want it to place the text (which can't be the plugin definition file that you created.

Hope that helps anyone in the future as that was a few things I came across

Comment: Those links are all dead now. Most commands are listed here: https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/commands.html